# How to get php validation working for a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, session

I need to validate the form before it gets sent to the session array, this is what I have so far.

Using `PHP_SELF` the form gets sent to the index which needs to verify that the input entered is correct and valid.

The error is echoed before the form is submitted and every time it is submitted with wrong inputs, the other messages do not echo. The page refreshes

Any help would be amazing, I have disabled my javascript validation to test this, and is half functional

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $mobileErr = $creditCardErr = $expiryErr = "";
    $name = $email = $mobile = $creditCard = $expiry = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        function validate($str) {
            return trim(htmlspecialchars($str));
        }

        //Valikdating User name
        if (empty($_POST["cust[name]"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = validate($_POST["cust[name]"]);

            if (!preg_match("/\b([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[A-Z]{1}[- \']{1}[A-Z]{0,1}  
    [a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[a-z]{1,2}[ -\']{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}){2,5}/",$name)) {
                $nameErr = "Only Western names, letters and white spaces allowed";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["cust[email]"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = validate($_POST["cust[email]"]);
            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["cust[mobile]"])) {
            $mobileErr = "Mobile Number is required";
        } else {
            $mobile = validate($_POST["cust[mobile]"]);
            //check if mobile phone is inputted correctly
            if (!preg_match("/^(\(04\)|04|\+614)( ?\d){8}$/",$mobile)) {
                $mobilelErr = "Invalid Mobile Number";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["cust[card]"])) {
            $creditCardErr = "Credit Card is required";
        } else {
            $creditCard = validate($_POST["cust[card]"]);
            //check if all credit card types are valid

            if (!preg_match("/^(\d){16}$/",$creditCard)) {

            }else if(!preg_match("/^(\d){4}\s{1}(\d){4}\s{1}(\d){4}\s{1}(\d){4}$/",$creditCard)) {

            }else if(!preg_match("/^(\d){4}\-{1}(\d){4}\-{1}(\d){4}\-{1}(\d){4}$/",$creditCard)) {
                $creditCardErr = "Invalid Credit Card";
            }
        }




        //This needs to be fixed
       if (empty($_POST["cust[expiry]"])) {
           $expiryErr = "Expiry is required";
       } else {
           $expiry = validate($_POST["cust[expiry]"]);
           //check if expiry is valid and a month ahead
           if (!preg_match("",$expiry)) {
               $expiryErr = "Invalid date, select month onwards";
           }
       }
   }
```

?>

**HTML Form Code:**

```
<div id="bookingsCard">
    <form  id="seatform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

        <!-- Customer Details -->
        <div class="CustomerDetails">

            <label for="CustomerDetails"><b>CUSTOMER DETAILS</b></label>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Name"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="cust[name]"  id="cust-name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="email" name="cust[email]" id='cust-email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Mobile"><b>Mobile</b></label>
            <input type="tel" name="cust[mobile]" id='cust-mobile' value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $mobileErr;?></span>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Credit Card"><b>Credit Card</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="cust[card]" id='cust-card' value="<?php echo $creditCard; ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $creditCardErr;?></span>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Expiry"><b>Expiry</b></label>
            <input type="month" name="cust[expiry]" id='cust-expiry' 
                                            pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" value="<?php echo $expiry; ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $expiryErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <label><b>Total Amount</b></label>
        <input  name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly>
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="bookbtn" name="order" value='order' id='bookbtn' >Book Now!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this : 
for html:  `<input type="text" required name="custname"  id="cust-name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>` don't know why you used cust[name] but i have used simplified name , and added html 5 validation `required` which makes life lot more easier .
And now after submitting the form php :

```
 if ( isset($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["name"])) {

 $name = $_POST["name"];
//your other validation

  } else {
      $nameErr = "Name is required/ not set";
  }
```

//hope it helps you happy coding

Comment: i need to check that all validation is in the session and then redirect to a receipt page. I have done the validation. Now i need to write in the SESSION to checl if all inputs are there and send to receipt.php

Comment: the task required the name to be cust[name] etc

Answer (score 0):

$_POST["cust[XXX]"]  is invalid. If you must use a 2d array to validate data, you should use $_POST['cust']['XXX'] instead. The code below works fine.

```
if (empty($_POST["cust"]['name'])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required"; 
} 
else {
    $name = validate($_POST["cust"]['name']);
    .............
}
```

The data you post using a form has already been serialised to an array called $_POST. To get an array inside an array, you need to use the syntax above.
If you do not have multiple instances of the form above, using a single dimension array in the form input should be fine.

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    ......
</form>
```

Then you can get the post data like the following:

```
<?php
   if(empty($_POST['name'])){
       $nameErr = 'Please input your name';
   }else{
       //Do something to process the value submitted
   }
?>
```